# Assign submission to a user referenced in a webform

Tags: webforms

I'm trying to solve this problem:

A webform contains a user entity reference field

User A submits a webform that references user B

After submitting the data I want user B to be able to edit this (and only this) submission.

I haven't found a way of doing this, is this possible.